# Drop duplicate rows that match the Header Row

Tags: python, duplicates, drop-duplicates

**Background**: I'm pulling NFL data in from a URL year by year and the header row is duplicated multiple times.

**Partial Solution**: I originally tried the .drop_duplicates() but it left me with two "header" rows (2*023 season hasn't finished so future games have different a different header row*). I assume because it was dropping duplicates, once there were only two left - they were considered "unique"?

**Ugly Solution**: I have solved my problem using a key word but I'm sure there's a better way to do this.

The line I'm using is as follows but I'm sure there's a better way:

```
    scorings_df = scorings_df[~scorings_df['Week'].str.contains("week", case=False, na=False)]
```

*Note the week column can contain both numbers and text depending on the week*

The full code is below, note that it is pulling 25 years of data so if you're going to run it - you might want to reduce that to 2/3 as you won't need all that

```
current_year=2023 

# Scoring History
url_scores = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/'

Scoring_df=pd.read_html(url_scores)[0]

# Create empty dataframe to store url data
Scoring_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Loop over the required number of years starting this year
for year in range(current_year, current_year -25, -1):
    # Generate the url string for each year    
    year_url_stats=f"{url_scores}{year}/games.htm"
    
    # Fetch the data from that url
    Scores = pd.read_html(year_url_stats)
    
    scorings_df=Scores[0]    # Ensure we're taking the first table on the url
    # Remove the Header Row duplicates (.drop_duplicates() not sufficient) & Future games
    scorings_df = scorings_df[~scorings_df['Week'].str.contains("week", case=False, na=False)]
    # Convert the 'Date' column to datetime for filtering
    scorings_df['TempDate'] = pd.to_datetime(scorings_df['Date'], errors='coerce')
    scorings_df = scorings_df[scorings_df['TempDate'] <= datetime.datetime.now()]
    scorings_df.drop(columns=['TempDate'], inplace=True)  


    # Add a column for 'Year' so we can filter later
    scorings_df['Year'] = year
    
    # Clean up Team names
    scorings_df['Winner/tie'] = scorings_df['Winner/tie'].str.split().str[-1]
    scorings_df['Loser/tie'] = scorings_df['Loser/tie'].str.split().str[-1]

    
    # Reorder columns (reduces from 15 to 13)
    columns_order = ['Year', 'Week', 'Day', 'Date', 'Time', 'Winner/tie', 'Loser/tie', 'PtsW', 'PtsL', 'YdsW', 'TOW', 'YdsL', 'TOL']
    scorings_df = scorings_df[columns_order]
    
    
    # Append to the dataframe
    Scoring_df = pd.concat([Scoring_df, scorings_df], ignore_index=True)
    
print(Scoring_df.head)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize the Pandas **drop_duplicates()** function in a different way.
import pandas as pd
import datetime

```
scoring_df = pd.DataFrame()  

for year in range(current_year, current_year - 25, -1):
    year_url_stats = f"{url_scores}{year}/games.htm"
    scores = pd.read_html(year_url_stats)
    scorings_df = scores[0]
    scorings_df = scorings_df[~scorings_df.apply(tuple, axis=1).duplicated()]
    scorings_df['TempDate'] = pd.to_datetime(scorings_df['Date'], errors='coerce')
    scorings_df = scorings_df[scorings_df['TempDate'] <= datetime.datetime.now()]
    scorings_df.drop(columns=['TempDate'], inplace=True)
    scorings_df['Year'] = year
    scorings_df['Winner/tie'] = scorings_df['Winner/tie'].str.split().str[-1]
    scorings_df['Loser/tie'] = scorings_df['Loser/tie'].str.split().str[-1]
    scoring_df = scoring_df.append(scorings_df)
```

Comment: That line worked! Thank you so much, I knew there had to be a way. 
    `scorings_df = scorings_df[~scorings_df.apply(tuple, axis=1).duplicated()]`